# how to delete an specific item from a foreign key within .views? Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im working on a Django app where you can join events only under the approval of the owner of the event.

By now, I have the function that adds the current user to the event for approval.

.views

```
@login_required
def request_event(request, pk):
    previous = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        Attending.objects.create(post=post, attendant=request.user)
        messages.success(request, f'Request sent!')
        return redirect(previous)
    except post.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')
```

and here is the function that deletes de user request (By now is deleting the request of the current logged user)

```
@login_required
def remove_attendant(request, pk):
    previous = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        #attendant = #post.attending_set.all
        Attending.objects.filter(post=post, attendant=request.user).delete()
        messages.success(request, f'User removed!')
        return redirect(previous)
    except post.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')
```

My situation here is that I'm a having problem to get the attendants of the event (all the users who where added as atendant), so that the owner can reject which ever request he want.

**How can I change this so that the function is going to delete a specific user of the event?**

Thanks!!

**Additional:**

models.py

```
class Attending(models.Model):
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    attendant = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='events_attending', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

urls.py

```
path('post/<int:pk>/remove_attendant/', views.remove_attendant, name='remove-attendant'),
```

.html

```
{% for user in object.attending_set.all %}
                <div class="d-flex mb-3 border-top pt-3">
                      <div class="p-2 align-self-center">
                        <div class="mr-1 d-inline-block" style="height:40px; width:40px;">
                            <img class="rounded-circle img-st-user-pro" src="{{ user.attendant.profile.image.url }}">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="p-2 align-self-center">
                        <h6 class="font-weight-bold mb-0">{{ user.attendant.first_name }}</h6>
                        <h6 class="mb-0 text-secondary">24 años</h6>
                      </div>
                      <div class="ml-auto p-2 align-self-center">
                        <a href="#" style="font-size: 14px !important;" class="btn-pre p-2 rounded text-decoration-none text-white pl-3 pr-3"><i class="pr-2 fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>Approve</a>
                        <a href="   /post/{{ object.pk }}/attendants/{{ object.pk_attendant }}/remove-attendant/" style="font-size: 14px !important;" class="bg-white p-2 rounded text-decoration-none text-dark border pl-3 pr-3 ml-2">Reject</a>
                      </div>


                </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the attendant ID in the URL. So, something like `posts/<int:pk_post>/attendants/<int:pk_attendant>/remove`.

```py
@login_required
def remove_attendant(request, pk_post, pk_attendant):
    previous = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    try:
        Attending.objects.filter(attendant_id=pk_attendant).delete()
        messages.success(request, f'User removed!')
        return redirect(previous)
    except post.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')
```

You might notice that you don't even need the post id in the URL. Your choice if you want to keep it. BTW, these thing are explained at great length in the Django tutorial.

Comment: Hi @vinkomlacic! Tried your answer but this is giving me a 404 error. Maybe because of the attendant_id=pk_attendant?

Comment: You're right. `pk=pk_attendant` is correct. I will edit the answer.

Comment: The url is correct @vinkomlacic ? as is not taking the PK of the attendant... <a href="   /post/{{ object.pk }}/attendants/{{ object.pk_attendant }}/remove-attendant/" </a>

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code. Cannot know without this. Don't know  what is the object in this case.

Comment: Also, `attendant_id` should be correct. I got confused before, but now I see that the attendant is the attribute of the Attending so it is correct.

Comment: Sure @vinkomlacic . Updated with html! This button is in a detailview. Thats why is an object.

Comment: I think it should go `{{ object.attendant.id }}` instead of `{{ object.pk_attendant }}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242554/discussion-between-chrislumber-and-vinkomlacic).